# Как из вложенного списка сделать 3 вложенных списка?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Есть список в списке:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Подскажите, как этот внутренний список превратить из одного в три внутренних списка?:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: По какому принципу? Список всегда должен быть разделен на три равные части? Или каждый подсписок должен состоять из пяти элементов, или не более чем из пяти элементов? А если длина списка не кратна трем?

Comment: длина всегда кратна 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def split(a, n):
    for i in range(0, len(a), n):
        yield a[i:i + n]

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

print(a)

a = list(split(a[0], 5))

print(a)
```